# How to prepend a string to err?

Tags: go

I'd like to prepend "Message" to err.

```
  x, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(s), 64) 
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Message" + err)
  }
```

I see the following error. Could anybody let me know how to add a string to err? Thanks.

test.go:24:37: invalid operation: "test.go" + err (mismatched types string and error)

Comment: err is of type error. If you want the error out of that you can use err.Error(). It also implements the stringer interface, so fmt.Printf("Message: %v", err) works in this case as well

Answer (score 2):

You should use [fmt.Errorf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf) function.

```
err = fmt.Errorf("prepend %w", err)
```

It wraps the error and effectively lets you add description to it.

[Full code](https://play.golang.org/p/0BJIdBFPPOt)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

func main() {
    err := errors.New("error")
    err = fmt.Errorf("prepend %w", err)
    panic (err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`log.Fatalf()`](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go?s=9702:9746#L313) or [`log.Fatalln()`](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go?s=9878:9908#L319) to format the logged output of `err.Error()` as follows :

```golang
log.Fatalf("Message %s", err.Error())
// or 
log.Fatalln("Message %s", err.Error())
```

Also have a look at package [errors](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/) which have useful functions regarding wrapping and unwrapping errors.